# Should I use finings when brewing a White/Weiss/Wheat beer?

Tags: weiss, wheat, belgian-white, finings

My latest brew is a Belgian White beer - a Hoegaarden stile beer.

I don't have the equipment to rack this beer so I intend to bottle it after about 3 weeks in the brew barrel.

This style of beer is usually a little cloudy in the glass, but my dilemma is whether I should be using finings with this brew.

Anyone with experience with this style of beer? Should I use finings or would this ruin it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not use finings, I like the cloudiness and believe it to be part of the style, I would not use anything to interfere with this.

Answer (score 3):

Adding finings is a waste of effort with this style when brewed correctly.
It is possible to have too much residual haze stuff in the beer and it will be super cloudy, and maybe even chunky.  If your normal pale ales are cloudy, maybe finings are a good idea with this wiesse attempt.

That said, some people actually add a little flour to the boil late to improve the cloudiness.  Your water chemistry may actually promote higher than average flocculation.  In that case, you may want to try the flour trick to help ensure proper cloudiness.

I'd say let it ride with out finings now, but then you can always make adjustments with the knowledge above later on.